# Eclipse RCP application starts only as administrator

Tags: java, windows, osgi, eclipse-rcp, guava

A few days ago we decided to start using Guava in our Eclipse RCP application. I downloaded guava-14.0.1.jar from http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/.

After I had started eclipse.exe the application crashed. The .metadata/.log file contained the following errors:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-08-12 15:56:32.033
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Optional
    at com.treeage.treeagepro.license.LicenseLevel.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.treeage.treeagepro.license.LicenseInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.treeage.treeagepro.license.LicenseManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.treeage.treeagepro.license.LicenseManager.getManager(Unknown Source)
    at com.treeage.treeagepro.app.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.internalBasicInitialize(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$28.runWithException(Workbench.java:1541)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.treeage.treeagepro.app.Application.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Optional
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

**There is no error if the application is running as an administrator.**

The application is 64 bit, so this is not an UAC virtualization issue. But it looks like the problem is somehow connected with permissions.

---

guava-14.0.1.jar seems to be a valid OSGi bundle: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=688 (At least I found all necessary headers in MANIFEST.MF)

Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you import your guava library?

Comment: The source of the problem completely changed. I have updated my question

Comment: Does your own bundle (the one that contains the LicenseLevel class) import the `com.google.common.base` package?

Comment: No, we use Require-Bundle header instead

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this and reduce it to a more minimalistic case? Does it happen in something that would just bootstrap a simpler app using Guava?

Comment: Also, does this happen when running the application from within Eclipse, or only on your packaged RCP app?

Comment: No, I can't reproduce. The most interesting is that this problem disappears if I install my app to a different folder (default is C:\Program Files\<app_name>, if I install to C:\Program Files\<app_name>2 - everything works fine) . So this is somehow connected with this particular folder. And yes, it doesn't happen when I run the application from Eclipse.

Comment: @Orionll: have you checked that particular folder's properties to check if it wasn't somehow modified to require some administrative rights for some actions?

Comment: @Orionll: reply with @<username>, otherwise people have no clue you replied to them. You get notifications becaue you are the OP, but answerers don't and they're not likely to manually monitor the N threads they participate in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by wiping out `C:\Users\<user_name>\.eclipse` folder. It looks like the problem was somehow connected with OSGi (Equinox) temporary directories.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you have included the bundle in the feature that you are using in the product configuration of your RCP.
Double check if you are using the right symbolic name and if you are requiring the right version.
I had a problem like yours because the guava jar was not being copied properly to the target platform at build time.

In my case I had to add the following in the feature.xml to ensure the version 0.14.1 was being copied since Eclipse Xtext and other components uses an older one:

```
<requires>
    <import plugin="com.google.guava" version="0.14.1"/>
    ....
</requires>
<plugin
     id="com.google.guava"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="0.0.0"
     unpack="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I'd think **this isn't Java or OSGi related**, but probably just a **filesystem permission issue**.

You may want to:

- check that particular folder and its subfolders and files for unusal permission requirements (right-click, properties, security tab),
- delete the entire folder, recreate it, and try again to check for a different outcome.